# Network configuration for isolated subnetwork with Internet Access

Tags: network, networking

I have been tasked with helping set up a subnetwork for my office, and due to limited experience with networking, wanted to get suggestions / recommendations for the best way to do this based on our current setup.

Our current office network runs from a baseline switch (3COM Model# 3CRBSG5293) that is connected to a hardware firewall (Zyxel Model# USG Flex 200). This in turn is connected to a layer 3 access switch (Cisco Model# ME-3400EG-2CS-A) that connects to a wall panel for outside internet connectivity.

We want to run a separate line from the layer 3 switch to a router or switch to create a small isolated private network that still has internet access, but doesn't communicate with any of our office devices on the main network.  We have to have the option to view the IP addresses of each machine on this private network and configure ports as needed.

On this subnetwork would be a windows computer to manage all devices on this new network via SSH, as well as several client machines (linux based) that connect to the internet to perform various tasks. This is for a new office space in our building that has nothing to do with our primary office, hence the need for a separate isolated network.

Any recommendations for whether a router or managed switch in between the new devices and the layer 3 switch would be better? I tried searching, but almost all of my results came back to connecting a layer 3 switch to a router for internet connectivity, and I am unable to change our current configuration.

I've never dealt with networking before, so this is new to me. If you require additional information or clarification, please let me know.

I have attached a picture of the current network with the proposed changes for clarification.  The current network has multiple devices connected to it on the 3COM Baseline Switch (12+ devices).  The new network will have at maximum 6-8 devices connected to it.

[image: Network Diagram]

Comment: Please edit your question to include a good network description or diagram, the network device models, and the network device configurations. How you will do that depends upon the missing information.

Comment: Please include the configuration for the Cisco ME-3400EG-2CS-A.

Comment: I unfortunately do not have access to the configuration of the Cisco AP as it is managed and controlled by the ISP itself.

Comment: That is where you really need to put your restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your new subnet requires basic protection from the outside Internet, so you need a router/firewall and DHCP server for automatic IP configuration. You might also need another switch if the router doesn't provide sufficient switched ports.

The upstream switch would need to be configured accordingly.

Another option is to add a new subnet to your already existing router on a routed port and appropriate firewall rules. While that is possible with most business-grade routers, for a device to on topic here the vendor must offer optional, paid support which Zyxel sadly don't.